# tdbc::odbc returns positive integers from a table holding a negative integer

Tags: oracle, odbc, tcl, tdbc

I am observing something strange with tcl tdbc::odbc.

When retrieving results from an table with a field defined as a number(5,0) and value that is negative in Oracle, the number returned is a positive number.

SQLPLUS, SQL DEVELOPER and using Julia ODBC package (using the same unixODBC drivers and dsn definition), the negative value is returned correctly, but only tcl tdbc::odbc package returns a positive value for a negative value

I've tried this test.

Create table in Oracle

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE 
(
  NUMBERONLY NUMBER 
, INTEGERONLY INTEGER 
, NUMBER5 NUMBER(5) 
);
```

Insert values

```
INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (NUMBERONLY, INTEGERONLY, NUMBER5) VALUES (-1, -1, -1)
```

then querying from SQLPLUS, everything is returned correctly.

```
SQL> select * from test_table;
NUMBERONLY INTEGERONLY    NUMBER5
---------- ----------- ----------
        -1          -1         -1
```

from Julia using ODBC with the same DSN definition, also correct.

```
julia> odbc_connection = ODBC.DSN("TEST", "TEST", "TEST")
julia> ODBC.query(odbc_connection, "select * from test_table")
1×3 DataFrames.DataFrame
|Row | NUMBERONLY | INTEGERONLY | NUMBER5 |
-------------------------------------------
| 1  | -1.0       | -1.0        | -1.0    |
```

then querying from Tcl, you can see the NUMBER5 table returns the wrong result

```
tdbc::odbc::connection create db "DSN=TEST; UID=TEST; PWD=TEST"
% db allrows "select * from test_table"
{NUMBERONLY -1.0 INTEGERONLY -1 NUMBER5 4294967295}
```

Note, if I call the query like this, then the result is correct

```
% db allrows "select cast(number5 as integer) number5 from test_table"
{NUMBER5 -1}
```

Is this a bug, or am I calling the function incorrectly.

Comment: -1 in 32-bit signed integers has the same bit pattern as 4294967295 in 32-bit unsigned integers. I don't know if that helps you…

Comment: @donal, yes I figured something like that, but are you saying this is designed this way from Tcl?  What would be the reason?

Comment: Better raise this question as a ticket at https://core.tcl.tk/tdbc/ticket, so the main contributor (Kevin Kenny) can take a look.

Comment: @mrcalvin OK, I've raised a ticket.